# centos/linux: run tftpd in a non-default net namespace

Tags: linux, centos, namespace, tftp

I wonder if anyone succeeded starting a `tftpd` in a network namespace (I'm using `tftp-server-5.2-22.el7.x86_64.rpm`)?
I.e., starting `tftpd` in a default NS is trivial:

```
bash# systemctl start tftp
bash# systemctl status tftp
* tftp.service - Tftp Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/tftp.service; indirect; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-08-28 05:32:00 PDT; 3s ago
...
```

However, if I try to modify its service-unit file, namely this line:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/in.tftpd -s /var/lib/tftpboot
```

prepending command with either `ip netns exec ns-red ...` or with `nsenter --net=/run/netns/ns-red ...`, it never works, the system logs throws these errors:

```
systemd[1]: tftp.service: Got no socket.
systemd[1]: tftp.service: Failed to run 'start' task: Invalid argument
systemd[1]: tftp.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start Tftp Server.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How have you built the `ns-red` namespace?

Comment: @StephenHarris, typically with `ip netns add ...` command

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after playing a bit with the tftp and service file, turns out the solution is rather simple - start `tftp` in a standalone mode (`-L` or `-l` options), rather than in `xinetd` environment.